# Android - how to drop a realm-database

Tags: android, realm

In my app, I need to create multiple `Realm` `database` with different name, example (`A.realm`, `B.realm`....).

Now I want to `delete (drop)` one of them, Is there any way to do it with `Realm` ?

I had google a lot but all result I get just clear all data in `database`, not `delete/drop` `database`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration)` :  https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#deleteRealm-io.realm.RealmConfiguration-

Comment: I got an exception as :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: It's not allowed to delete the file associated with an open Realm. Remember to close() all the instances of the Realm before deleting its file.

So is there any way to force-close all of the instances of Realm ?

Comment: No, you should manually call close for every time you called `getInstance()`. See e.g. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances

Comment: One more question that do I need to close Realm when I use excuteTransaction() ?

Comment: No, you should only close it when you no longer need to read from Realm

Comment: I mean with below action :realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        // begin & end transcation calls are done for you
        Dog theDog = realm.where(Dog.class).equals("age", 1).findFirst();
        theDog.setAge(3);
        realm.close();
    }
}
Do I need to call realm.close() inside execute method like above

Comment: No, that should be handled for you.

Comment: thank you so much @Christian, but please help for one more question: when I create an Realm instance but not beginTransaction() (just for query data) do I need to close above instance of Realm?

Comment: Yes, in that case you do.